# I accidentally clicked "ignore" when Chrome asked if I wanted to use a protocol handler. How do I "un-ignore" it?

Tags: google-chrome

I accidentally ignored the `gd.pool` protocol handler on Gamedesire.com when Google Chrome asked me to choose default application for this type of link, and I can't find out how to make it prompt me again.

How can I reassign this protocol handler, or make Chrome prompt me again?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Chrome's documentation on protocol handlers](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1382847?hl=en), you can change the default handlers in the Manage Handlers dialog:

1. Click the Crome Menu button
2. Select **Settings > Show advanced settings**
3. Click **Content Settings** inside the **Privacy** section
4. Find the **Handlers** section
5. Click **Manage Handlers**

You can add, remove, and update protocol handlers here. Additionally, you can right-click on a link and select **Open link With...* to pick a one-time handler to use without changing your default.

Comment: This answer seems dated. Manage Handlers doesn't show that I'm ignoring a protocol and I don't see "Open link With..." when I right click the link in Chrome 39.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn It seems up to date to me. Can you provide a more specific example where this is not working? What protocol are you wanting a website to handle, and which website are you visiting that wants to handle it?

Comment: Magnet. It may not be that its not up to date, it might just be that this won't list protocol handlers for external programs.

Comment: No, I don't think it does. I think this is for if a website (e.g., GMail) wants to handle links from other programs on your computer (e.g., all `mailto` links). Modifying stuff in there makes Windows on my system pop up and ask if I want chrome to handle that protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Google stupidly crippled the preferences UI so you can't edit the protocol handlers any longer that you established by answering the little dialog ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2Hbi.png)) with "Always open ...". What I did to solve my problem (assuming Chrome "Default" profile):

**End Chrome. Then edit this text file:**

`C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences`

It's all in one line, not meant for human editing. If your editor (e.g. [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/)) features language highlighting, choose JSON.

I had to change the text
`"protocol_handler":{"excluded_schemes":{"mql4buy":false}},`
to
`"protocol_handler":{"excluded_schemes":{}},`
so I just removed
`"mql4buy":false`

This was for the custom protocol link `mql4buy://(etc)`

Since your problem is that your protocol is ignored, maybe you have an entry for your protocol saying ":true".

Comment: Thank you! Every other article on the internet was missing the crucial part of "Default" in the user data folder. It may be because Chrome has updated and made all the other answers invalid.