# Accidentally told Chrome to ignore Protocol Handler?

Tags: google-chrome

I clicked a magnet link and Chrome gave me the popup saying "This site is trying to open an external app." I clicked the checkbox for it to never ask me again but I accidentally clicked the "Do Nothing" button. Now I can't seem to revert that decision.

As per [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/624119/i-accidentally-clicked-ignore-when-chrome-asked-if-i-wanted-to-use-a-protocol), if I go to Settings > Content Settings (under Privacy) > "Manage Handlers..." nothing is listed. Right clicking a magnet link does not provide an "Open Link With..." option either. The question seems to be outdated.

Comment: Can you try the solution from this link?. https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/sPhxiTQlf4s

Comment: I've looked into it but it says I can only register a handler from the document's origin. I can't use that to register an external application.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change protocol handler to desktop app (like mapping URL:IRC to mIRC)](https://superuser.com/questions/984617/change-protocol-handler-to-desktop-app-like-mapping-urlirc-to-mirc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little Googling, [I found the answer](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/ZV2wifw51A4).

Ensure Chrome is completely closed. No lingering extensions or icon in the system tray. Navigate to `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data` and there is a file named `local state`. Inside the file, look for `protocol_handler` and under that you'll find `magnet: true,` change it to false and save the file.

Following these instructions fixed my magnet problem.

Comment: Everything online says to do this, but it doesn't work on OSX, there is nothing matching the protocol handler I'm looking for :'(

Comment: @Meekohi It is in file `./Preferences` instead.

Comment: This did not work for me on windows 10.  There is no protocol_handler section in local state file.  Also, cant find any Preferences file on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

For Google Chrome version 108.x on Windows 10

1. Close Google Chrome
2. Go to `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\`
3. Open file `Preferences` with a text editor
4. Look for `protocol_handler` and you will find `<protocol>: true`. Set it to `false` and save the file

Answer (score -2):

The answer above did not work for me. But [this one](https://superuser.com/a/1255390/669391) worked: (dont upvote my answer but his)

> 1) Goto URL chrome://settings/clearBrowserData
>
> 2) Select duration "Past week".
>
> 3) Select only "Cookies and other site data"
>
> 4) Click "Clear Browsing Data" and browse site again.