# Change protocol handler to desktop app (like mapping URL:IRC to mIRC)

Tags: windows, windows-10, file-association, protocol-handler

I'm trying to change the IRC protocol handler. Must I use a Store app as the below illustration somewhat suggests?

---

[image: Set Associations in Windows 10.]

<sub>The image shows that Windows is expecting the default program to be an app from the Store. Interestingly, the current setting is Google Chrome, a desktop app.</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### I'm trying to change the IRC protocol handler

Below is a solution for Windows 8. A similar/identical procedure should work for Windows 10.

**Warning**:

The instructions below contain steps that tell you how to modify the registry. However, serious problems might occur if you modify the registry incorrectly.

Therefore, make sure that you follow these steps carefully. For added protection, back up the registry before you modify it. Then, you can restore the registry if a problem occurs.

For more information see [How to back up and restore the registry in Windows.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322756)

---

#### Changing the IRC protocol association on Windows 8

> I would like to remove Google Chrome's association with the IRC protocol. If I open an IRC link from Run, such as irc://irc.neowin.net/neowin, Google Chrome opens. I would like mIRC to be associated with this protocol.
>
> I've tried removing the association using Set Default Programs, but have had no success. It will only allow me to change it to a Windows 8 (store) app.

Solution:

> I was able to remove the IRC association from Google Chrome by making this simple registry change:
>
> 1. Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet\Google Chrome\Capabilities\URLAssociations\`
> 2. Then delete the `IRC` line
>
> That's it. I tested it on my Windows 8 machine and clicking on an IRC
>   link in Chrome launches mIRC and prompts me to connect to the server.
>
> This is assuming you have the IRC links assosicated with mIRC.
>
> I made a simple registry file that will make the Chrome changes as
>   well as associate IRC and XDCC links to mIRC:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\irc]

@="URL: IRC Protocol"

"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\irc\shell\open\command]

@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\mIRC\\mirc.exe %1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\xdcc]

@="URL: XDCC Protocol"

"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\xdcc\shell\open\command]

@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\mIRC\\mirc.exe %1"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet\Google Chrome\Capabilities\URLAssociations]

"irc"=-
```

Source [Changing the IRC protocol association on Windows 8](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1132920-changing-the-irc-protocol-association-on-windows-8/)

Comment: Thanks, this works. I'm going to leave it unaccepted for a bit. I have to think about a general solution and what my question was asking.

Comment: What do you mean by a general solution?

Comment: mIRC was just an example it happened with. But I'm assuming it happens with any protocol/program, not just IRC.

Comment: The solution will be the same, just change the protocol name.

Comment: Yep, I think that's right. I can't look at it now but I wanted to think about that and come back to make an edit for the accept

Comment: This doesn't work for me on Windows 10. I had those registry entries already set to HexChat IRC client but the default protocol app setting in Windows 10 Settings is the one which seems to always take precedence.